# How to add lines between points without "touching" the points, like in "type='b'"?

Tags: r, plot, line

I would like to add lines between points in a plot in R.
But not between all of them.

So I use "lines".
But I would like to keep the "type='b'" style, with the line stopping just before the point.

Answer (score 10):

If ggplot is your thing, give this a whirl. ggplot doesn't natively support the `type = "b"` as in base graphics. We can get around that though with some overplotting and subsetting:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1, pi, pi/36)
y <- sin(x)
z <- data.frame(x,y)



ggplot(z, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line(data = subset(z, x > 1.5 & x < 2.5)) + 
    geom_point(size = 6, colour = "white") +
    geom_point(size = 3, colour = "black") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: doh - big picture, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

Set up some data

```
x <- seq(1, pi, pi/36)
y <- sin(x)
```

Create plot with all points

```
plot(x, y)
```

Add lines of `type="b"` for some of the points:

```
lines(x[10:20], y[10:20], type="b")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lines function with type='c' to just add the lines with the spaces around the points.  Just give the lines function the subset that you are interested in doing the lines for.